# Delete files from Google drive using python through google drive api

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to delete files from my google-drive using google drive apis for python.
I am able to retrieve the list of parents/children for a particular folder but when I try to delete one of the retrieved parent of the folder it gives me below error.
"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1j1sZ-0OAiTE9836bhTTpkUf3i4AFAvmG/parents/0AO-cNLqoD0BFUk9PVA? returned "Insufficient Permission">"
I have defined "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" as my scope. 
The same file got deleted when I tried "try this API" option from 
developer-google.com but it does not work from my python code.
Is there anything else in the configuration that I need for deleting the files.

Thanks.

Comment: Check you're using the correct file id

Comment: What authentication are you using? OAuth2 or through use of a service account?

Comment: If you want to delete files you should use 'files.delete' or update the file to trashed=true, if you remove the parents from a file it will become orphan. Also, that parent ID seems to be a teamdriveId, check that you have full access in order to be able to delete the file.